# Replace min and max values with predefined values in r

Tags: r, replace

I would like to replace the minimum and maximum values in a column with predefined min and max values.

Here is a sample dataset:

```
ids <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
scores.a <- c(512,531,541,555,562,565,570,572,573,588)

data <- data.frame(ids, scores.a)

min <- 520
max <- 595

> data
   ids scores.a
1    1      512
2    2      531
3    3      541
4    4      555
5    5      562
6    6      565
7    7      570
8    8      572
9    9      573
10  10      588
```

So, I need to replace 512 with 520 and 588 with 595.

```
The desired output is:
    > data
       ids scores.a
    1    1      520
    2    2      531
    3    3      541
    4    4      555
    5    5      562
    6    6      565
    7    7      570
    8    8      572
    9    9      573
    10  10      595
```

ANy ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a logical condition with `range` and `replace` (assuming there are no ties for `min/max`

```
datas$scores.a <- with(data, replace(scores.a, scores.a %in% 
                range(scores.a), c(min, max)))
```

If there are `ties`, an option is `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   mutate(scores.a = case_when(scores.a == min(scores.a) ~ min,
                 scores.a == max(scores.a) ~ max,
                 TRUE ~ scores.a))
```

-output

```
#   ids scores.a
#1    1      520
#2    2      531
#3    3      541
#4    4      555
#5    5      562
#6    6      565
#7    7      570
#8    8      572
#9    9      573
#10  10      595
```

NOTE: It is better to use a different name for object than a function name (`min`, `max`)